# Safari is parsing ISO 8601 date-time strings without timezone as UTC rather than Local

Tags: javascript, safari

According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Date_Time_String_Format) date-time strings without a time zone should be interpreted as local time.

> When the time zone offset is absent, date-only forms are interpreted as a UTC time and date-time forms are interpreted as local time.

Our API returns time stamps of various different time zones but we always want to display them in those different time zones (these are flight times and are always shown as local to the airport).

In most browsers I can pass this string to a Date object and it is interpreted as the user's local time zone but I don't care that it's the wrong time zone since we don't compare Dates across time zones. When I use `Intl.DateTimeFormat.format` to display it as a string it displays the same time as the string specifies which is what I want.

In Safari these time strings are interpreted as UTC and then the string format converts it to local time.

```js
new Date("2020-05-06T13:25:00").getTime() === new Date("2020-05-06T13:25:00Z").getTime()
```

This returns true in Safari but false everywhere else. (It will also return true if your local timezone is UTC but we're not considering that case).

[image: new Date in Safari]

This is Safari running on a computer set to CDT. It taken 13:25 as UTC then displaying it with -5 hours.

[image: new Date in Chrome]

This is Chrome (on Windows - not sure if that's relevant, I don't have access to a Mac). But it's taking the same timestamp as being local time and so then displays it as the same time. This is what I want.

Is there anyway we can work around this so I can return a time stamp which is then parsed as local time so it displays correctly.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be happening in Safari 15. Does anyone know what version of Safari fixed this?

Comment: It's fixed in Safari 14(.1)